# Remove special HTML characters from labels or textfields in flex (mxml)

Tags: html, apache-flex, special-characters, mxml, htmlspecialchars

I'm loading data with an RSS feed into a Flex application.
Some of the data has html special characters. It can't read é,è,à,ç and other similar letters that are used in French for example. It gives a strange code instead of the letters with accents.

Now I use  for reading HTML texts in Flex, but how can I remove these special characters?

Thanks!

Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

use "restrict" property of the component so that it takes some specific type of string. Something like mentioned below

myTextBox.restrict = "A-Z a-z 0-9",

Comment: This restricts characters when user in typing characters into TextInput control. In this case data is fetched from RSS feed, which includes "invalid" characters. It depends where do you want to show this data. I don't think this is the correct answer for this.

Comment: yeah, in case data is retrieved from somewhere else then we have to remove the invalid characters. Then Regular Expression is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) for removing those French letters.